# Uniform continuity, a direct proof

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

A common question in analysis is: Let $I$ be an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$. Show that a continuous function $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous iff for all sequences $(x_n), (y_n) \subset I$ such that $\vert x_n - y_n \vert \to 0$ then $\vert f(x_n) - f(y_n) \vert \to 0$.

The standard way to prove the converse direction is via the contrapositive, see for example: 
[Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous $\iff$ $\bar d(f(x_n),f(y_n)) \to 0$ for all sequences $\{x_n\}, \{y_n\}$ in $X$ with $d(x_n, y_n) \to 0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798989/show-that-f-is-uniformly-continuous-iff-bar-dfx-n-fy-n-to-0-for-a)

How would I prove it directly? ie, without the need for contrapositive.

Comment: Is $I$ an interval?  Open? Closed? Thanks.

Comment: @user46944 I don't think that matters at all in this case.

Comment: @DonAntonio So $I$ is just some subset of $\Bbb R$ with the subspace topology?

Comment: @user46944 I guess so, though that symbol is also widely used for the closed unit interval $\;[0,1]\;$ .

Comment: It's open, sorry edited now

Comment: Somewhat related: [Heine–Cantor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem)